# how to load an external URL in an iframe using wicket 6 (without using javascript)?

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications, iframe, wicket, wicket-1.6

I would like to load a website in an iframe in my own site.

I am using wicket 6. This is what I have tried so far:

```
    RedirectPage page = new RedirectPage ( link );
    InlineFrame frame = new InlineFrame ("myFrame", page );
    add (frame);
```

Works in every browser except Internet Explorer. Is there another better way to load the website? Incidentally it might solve my problem with Explorer which I'm guessing has something to do with the URL's parameter enconding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem: it seems that IE disallows parameters in the URL for iframes, and that was the cause of my errors: one when it converted '&' to '& amp;' and the other when it tried to load the page without parameters once the "&" where set correctly. I didn't get any further. There are probably some workarounds but it doesn't seem too easy.